# Ideals in polynomial rings can be characterized? (Easy question)

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I am trying to solve the following question. Let $F \leq K$ be fields and $\bar{a}$ a tuple of elements in $K$. Let $\bar{F}$ be the algebraic closure of $F$.
Let $I=\{ Q(\bar{x})\in F[\bar{x}] \ | \ Q(\bar{a})=0\}$ and $\bar{I}= \{ Q(\bar{x})\in \bar{F}[\bar{x}] \ | \ Q(\bar{a})=0\}$. Because $F[x]$ is noetherian then $I$ is finitely generated by a finite set of polynomials $P_{1}(\bar{x}), \dots, P_{n}(\bar{x}) \in F[\bar{x}]$. Denote $J$ the ideal in $\bar{F}[\bar{x}]$ generated by $(P_{1}(\bar{x}),\dots, P_{n}(\bar{x}))$.\
Is it the case that $J=\bar{I}$? Clearly $J \subseteq \bar{I}$ but I am wondering if the other direction will hold or not.

Comment: If $\overline{a}=(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$, then $I=(x_1-a_1,x_2-a_2,...,x_n-a_n)$ and $\overline{I}$ is generated by those same generators. Now, if $P_1,...,P_2$ generate $I$, therefore, $x_i-a_i$ are generated by the $P_i$ using polynomials in $K[\overline{x}]$. Therefore, those same combinations exist in $\overline{K}[\overline{x}]$. So, $J\supset \overline{I}$.

Comment: sorry, yes. I worte the first question in a silly way. I am not able to see the point inside the field. Say $\bar{a}$ is in some extension. Thanks for your help!